# Tiled .tmx Image rendering with SpriteKit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tiled, tmx

I have created a tiled .tmx file to create an orthogonal maze type game (my first attempt at writing a game). Is there a customary way to render images in iOS using SpriteKit?

There doesn't seem to be much written about this with regards to Swift. Some pointers in the right direction is all I need.

Comment: For future reference, JSTileMap worked for me - though there is not a lot out there about its use with Swift.

Comment: Scored a tumbleweed with this one.